# Should a kd tree be balanced like a binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, kdtree

I tried coding a kd tree and a binary search tree. I'm wondering why the bst gives me stack overflow error when inserting unbalanced data while the kd tree does not.

code for the binary search tree:

```
void insert(node *&_node, int _val) { //bst insert function, will change raw pointers to smart pointers later
    if (_node == NULL) {
        _node = new node;
        _node->val = _val;
    }
    else if (_node->val > _val)
        insert(_node->left, _val);
    else if (_node->val < _val)
        insert(_node->right, _val);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4000;i++) { //inserting unbalanced data, gives me stack overflow error
    test.insert(test.root, i);
}
```

code for the kd-tree:

```
void insert(Nodeptr &node, int point[], int depth) { //kd tree insert function, Nodeptr is a typedef of unique_ptr<Node>
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = Nodeptr(new Node(point));
        node->axis = depth%dim;
    }
    else if (node->pt[depth%dim] > point[depth%dim])
        insert(node->left, point, depth+1);
    else if (node->pt[depth%dim] < point[depth%dim])
        insert(node->right, point, depth+1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) { // inserting unbalanced data, does not give me stack overflow error
    point[0] = i;
    point[1] = i;
    tree.insert(tree.root, point, 0);
}
```

edit: visual studio says that may heap size is 224.57kb and created 3746 nodes when exception occured, so it didnt really complete 4000 insertions

Comment: Could you paste a stack trace? Did you try to debug?

Comment: Are you calling both methods in one process while executing the program or executing one after other and observed stack overflow??

Comment: @pawamoy i dont know how to do a stack trace, will paste after i figure it out

Comment: @they are in a different cpp file, executing one at a time

Comment: try doing 50,000 with kd tree, or even bigger